# Kendo-Knockout: How to center window

Tags: knockout.js, kendo-ui

I am using RPNiemeyer`s kendo-knockout library. I have a kendo window which I use like this in the html:

```
<div data-bind="kendoWindow: { isOpen: isOpen, title:'States', width: 600, height: 150, modal: true, resizable: false, actions: ['Maximize', 'Close'] }" > </div>
```

I used to center the dialog like this:

```
$('#productionStates').data("kendoWindow").center();
```

But as `center` is a method I cannot pass it in the markup like this `center: true`. In the kendo-knockout documentation there is a property widget for some of the widgets and my guess is that this is the key but I am not sure how to use it as there are no examples. Any ideas will be welcome. Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `widget` parameter is intended to be used when you need to interact with a widget in a way that is not supported by the provided binding options.  Normally, this is kind of a last resort, but in this case it looks like it would be the right choice.

What you do is pass an observable into the `widget` parameter and it will get filled with the actual widget.  Then, you can call methods off of it from your view model.

Something like:

```
var ViewModel = function() {
   this.isOpen = ko.observable(false);
   //center it if it is opened
   this.isOpen.subscribe(function(newValue) {
       if (newValue) {
           this.myWidget().center();         
       }
   }, this);

   //hold the widget
   this.myWidget = ko.observable();
};
```

Then, in markup:

```
<div data-bind="kendoWindow: { isOpen: isOpen, visible: false, modal: true, widget: myWidget }">
     ...
</div>​
```

Sample here: http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/gNgDm/

Comment: Thanks! Do You intend to add this functionality as a boolean property to your library? In my experience, everytime I need a modal window it need to be centered. Why always write logic to call method to explicitly do so ?

Comment: It is a bit challenging because there is no concept of `center` / `uncenter` and no events to know if the window is no longer centered (to set it to false) or now centered (to set it to true). It really does seem like it should be a configuration option that Kendo UI supports for it.  I would have to think about it a bit more, but it doesn't quite fit the normal "binding" pattern.  I can certainly see how it would be more convenient though.

Answer (score 6):

I actually achieved the same effect as Niemeyer by sticking it in the binding handler:

```
 

    ko.bindingHandlers.kendoWindow.options = {
        open: function () { this.element.data('kendoWindow').center(); }
    };
```

No additional binding needed, but it does tie up your "onOpen" event.